# change many word in content by wordpress filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

I using `wordpress` filter to change many word in content by this code bellow

```
function upperworld ($content){

    $string1 = array('1' => 'BA YEU CON', '2' => 'CON YEU ME' );
    $string = array('1' => 'abc', '2' => 'ccb' );

    foreach ($string as $key => $thay) {
        foreach ($string1 as $key => $canthay) {
            $content = str_replace($thay, $canthay, $content)
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'upperworld' );
```

It not working, please help me to fix it

Comment: Can you write what issue you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the below code to change the word in `the_content()`

```
function upperworld ($content){
    $string1 = array('1' => 'BA YEU CON', '2' => 'CON YEU ME' );
    $string = array('1' => 'abc', '2' => 'ccb' );
    foreach ($string1 as $key => $canthay) {
        $thay = $string[$key];
            $content = str_replace($thay, $canthay, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'upperworld' );
```

Comment: Okay great 

Comment: can you accept that answer.. If it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

you are missed the `;` in the statement of `$content = str_replace($thay, $canthay, $content);`

update your code by this

```
foreach ($string as $key => $thay) {
    foreach ($string1 as $key => $canthay) {
        $content = str_replace($thay, $canthay, $content);
    }
}
```

OR

```
$content = preg_replace(array_map(function($row){return "/{$row}/";}, $string), $string1, $content);
```